# Selecting AND Counting to return in ASP.NET Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, count, repeater

I am trying to make a repeater, that prints out Every category of my forum, and also to the left of it, a count to show, how many 'Threads' is connected to this Category (Inside it).

This is my SQL, that perfectly shows the correct number of threads, but that's it. I can only use 'threadCount' as Eval in my ASP.NET. This is ofcourse, what i wan't, but i also want to be able to write out the Category name aswell, but i can't be allowed to do so, because this query only returns the count, and not the whole thing from INNER JOINS.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'threadCount'
FROM threads INNER JOIN
             categories ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is your query. It should be something like:

```
SELECT categories.category_name, COUNT(1) AS 'threadCount'
FROM threads
INNER JOIN categories
    ON categories.category_id = threads.thread_category_id
GROUP BY categories.category_name
```

You cannot use `Eval` in fields you are not selecting from the database.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you very much mate! I'll accept your answer, as soon as i can!

Comment: Btw, i was wondering, is it possible to extend this, so i can select more than just category_name ?

Comment: Yes, you just have to add the fields you want in the select AND in the group by

Comment: Thanks, now, i got another issue with that, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247918/sql-counter-and-returner-doubles-the-result